# How to design a query to pop up input with two text boxes in MS Access

Tags: query, ms-access

I ask this question while I could not find any similar question neither on Google nor DBA Stackexchange, this question might be duplicated.
I wrote this query in MS access to check for first name and surname. But every time I run the query, I see two little input boxes which come after each other. I want to change my query so that I enter first name and surname in One/Single input box.
**How can I design something like this?**
Here is what I achieved up until this point:

```
SELECT tblGuests.firstname, tblGuests.surname
FROM tblGuests
WHERE (((tblGuests.firstname) Like "*" & [Enter Firstname] & "*") OR ((tblGuests.surname) Like "*" & [Enter Surname] & "*"));
```

Comment: Queries don't pop input or make text boxes. It sounds like you are confusing queries and forms.

Answer (score 0):

The query that would display both names in one text box looks like this:

```
SELECT tblGuests.FirstName & " " & tblGuests.LastName As FullName
FROM tblGuests;
```

This is not updatable or searchable. Those are functions of `Forms` and not `Queries`.